# last object returned in chrome dev tools / python / irb /

Tags: python, javascript, ruby, matlab

In matlab one could type in the following and get the following reply:

```
matlab> 1+1
ans = 2
```

One could then all the last returned object by simply typing:

```
matlab> ans 
ans = 2
```

That is, the last output seems to be saved in an object named `ans`. For this rather useful if you are playing around with a little code for some rapid prototyping.

I now wonder if ipython, irb and javascript in the chrome dev tools console have similar functionality and if so, how to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Chrome Developer Console, whenever you select a value, or an element, you can re-display it by typing `$_`.

Try this:

1. Go into Chrome Development Tools on this page
2. Open the console
3. Type `$("code")`, for example - will show all the code elements on the page
4. Type `$_` and you'll see the exact result again

Try your sample: type `1 + 1` -> yields `2`. Type `$_` -> `2`.